# How to put an image on web browser control

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In the web browser app for windows phone 7,i have created a web browser control(in xaml.cs) on the Grid. After that i have created an image on the Grid. But when i open the web browser in emulator, that image is not visible. It's a tabbed browser. **But the image is visible in the grid but not visible on web browser control(After debugging the app)**. Like the UC Browser has this thing. PLease the below images, on the grid, the image is visible but on the web browser control, the image is not visible.

[image]    [image]
[image]

**In .xaml**

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox x:Name="UrlTextBox" Background="White" InputScope="URL" KeyDown="UrlTextBox_KeyDown" Margin="0,0,98,0" GotFocus="UrlTextBox_GotFocus" LostFocus="UrlTextBox_LostFocus" KeyUp="UrlTextBox_KeyUp"/>
    <Grid x:Name="BrowserHost" 
      Grid.Row="1" GotFocus="BrowserHost_GotFocus">
        <Image x:Name="Full" Source="Images/full.png" Height="60" Width="60" Margin="430,678,0,0" MouseEnter="Full_MouseEnter" Visibility="Visible" />
    </Grid>
```

**In Xaml.cs**

```
private void ShowTab(int index) 
{ 
    this.currentIndex = index;       
    UrlTextBox.Text = this.urls[this.currentIndex] ?? "Search"; 
    if (this.browsers[this.currentIndex] == null) 
    { 
        WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser(); 
        this.browsers[this.currentIndex] = browser; 
        BrowserHost.Children.Add(browser); 
        browser.IsScriptEnabled = true; 
    } 
    for (int i = 0; i < NumTabs; i++) 
    { 
        if (this.browsers[i] != null) 
        { 
            this.browsers[i].Visibility = i == this.currentIndex ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

I need that image in my web browser control. Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance for your hard work!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create an image on the web browser control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732156/create-an-image-on-the-web-browser-control)

Comment: don't delete a question, then re-ask it.  That's bad form for SO.

Comment: Can anybody help me with this? I am really stucked in this.

Comment: @MattLacey Now i have edited my post with some images that shows my problem. I really need your help.

Comment: @Robaticus Now i have edited my post with some images that shows my problem. I really need your help.

Comment: @MattLacey Can you check this out- http://stackoverflow.com/q/10758225/1392194

Comment: @Robaticus Can you check this out- http://stackoverflow.com/q/10758225/1392194

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WHen you are adding the browser control in code, you are putting it on top of the image.  You need a container within the Grid to hold your controls.  Ultimately, though, you should probably try to set this up in XAML the way Matt Lacey shows above.

If you want do try this *your* way, you need something like this:

```xml
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox x:Name="UrlTextBox" Background="White" InputScope="URL" KeyDown="UrlTextBox_KeyDown" Margin="0,0,98,0" GotFocus="UrlTextBox_GotFocus" LostFocus="UrlTextBox_LostFocus" KeyUp="UrlTextBox_KeyUp"/>
    <Grid x:Name="BrowserHost" 
  Grid.Row="1" GotFocus="BrowserHost_GotFocus">
        <Grid x:Name="BrowserHolder"/>
        <Image x:Name="Full" Source="Images/Full.png" Height="60" Width="60" Margin="430,678,0,0" MouseEnter="Full_MouseEnter" Visibility="Visible" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Notice the addition of the Grid "BrowserHolder".  Since that one was added first, anything that you add to that control *should* appear behind the image.

So your code then becomes:

```cs
private void ShowTab(int index) 
{ 
    this.currentIndex = index;       
    UrlTextBox.Text = this.urls[this.currentIndex] ?? "Search"; 
    if (this.browsers[this.currentIndex] == null) 
    { 
        WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser(); 
        this.browsers[this.currentIndex] = browser; 

        // NOTE: Changed to BrowserHolder
        BrowserHolder.Children.Add(browser); 

        browser.IsScriptEnabled = true; 
    } 
    for (int i = 0; i < NumTabs; i++) 
    { 
        if (this.browsers[i] != null) 
        { 
            this.browsers[i].Visibility = i == this.currentIndex ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Awesome Robaticus, It worked perfectly. Thank you all so much.

Answer (score 1):

In a brand new app, in MainPage.xaml I replaced

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0"></Grid>
```

with

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="theBrowser" />
    <Image Source="/Background.png"
           Stretch="None"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
</Grid>
```

Then in the page constructor I added

```
theBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com/"));
```

This lead to a display like:

[image: look it works - Note: screenshot taken in light theme]

This proves it's perfectly popssible.
Unfortunately your incomplete sample in your question (the XAML) and code that has no bearing on your actual question (the .cs) makes it hard to say exactly why you can't get it to work.

Additionally, please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints before posting further and ask future questions in a way that will make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: That's the problem here, if you see my post you can notice that i have not created web browser control through .xaml. First i have created a grid and then added a web browser control through codes(in .xaml.cs). That's why the image is not getting visible. Please help!

Comment: If you're generating them through code set the `Canvas.ZIndex` to determine/control what is on top.