# Want to search in google

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In the web browser app for windows phone7, If the user types simply **"bing.com"** in the UrlTExtBox, the UrlTextBox auto-fills **"http://www."** The following codes shows that. At the same time if the user types simply words(like technology or project glass) without **".com"**, the UrlTextBox again auto-fills with **"http://"**. But i need, if there is only words then it should search in Google or Bing. Can anybode help me with this? Thanks in advance for your hard work!

```
 private void UrlTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            Uri url;
            if (Uri.TryCreate(UrlTextBox.Text, UriKind.Absolute, out url))
            {
                this.urls[this.currentIndex] = UrlTextBox.Text;
                this.browsers[this.currentIndex].Navigate(url);
                navigationcancelled = false;
                this.browsers[this.currentIndex].Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                Navigate(UrlTextBox.Text);
            }
        }
    }

 private void Navigate(String address)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(address)) return;
        if (address.Equals("about:blank")) return;
        if (!address.StartsWith("http://") &&
            !address.StartsWith("https://"))
        {
            address = "http://" + address;
        }
        try
        {
            browsers[this.currentIndex].Navigate(new Uri(address));
        }
        catch (System.UriFormatException)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got an idea for Matt Lacey's answer. Just add one more if statement to the Navigate.

```
        if (!address.Contains("."))
        {
            address = " ";
            browsers[this.currentIndex].Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.com/search?q=" + UrlTextBox.Text, UriKind.Absolute));
        }
```

The point is, if i didn't add **address = " ";** then the UrlTextBox auto-fills **http://**.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you split it by `.`, and then if array count is one you know it's a single word and should add .com, else you should treat it as a proper link.

Comment: I tried this but what happens you know, whatever i type into the textbox that navigates to search in google(even proper links).

Answer (score 0):

In your navivate function check if it is one word in the box, if so check if it ends with .com or .net etc.. if so, add http and send it along, if not append it to the google search url.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple **console** app which demonstrates the logic you should be looking for:

```
namespace SO10747736
{
    using System;

    internal enum TestResult
    {
        TryCreatePass,
        ValidWithPrefix,
        Search,
        DoNothing,
        Unknown
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test("http://example.com", TestResult.TryCreatePass);
            Test("https://example.com", TestResult.TryCreatePass);
            Test("https://example", TestResult.TryCreatePass);
            Test("example.com", TestResult.ValidWithPrefix);
            Test("example", TestResult.Search);
            Test("another example", TestResult.Search);
            Test(null, TestResult.DoNothing);
            Test(string.Empty, TestResult.DoNothing);
            Test("  ", TestResult.DoNothing);
            Test("about:blank", TestResult.DoNothing);

            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

        private static void Test(string toTest, TestResult expectedResult)
        {
            var result = SimulateEnterkeyPressed(toTest);

            if (result == expectedResult)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} was parsed correctly", toTest);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("*** {0} was NOT parsed correctly and returned {1} ***", toTest, result);
            }
        }

        private static TestResult SimulateEnterkeyPressed(string toTest)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(toTest))
            {
                return TestResult.DoNothing;
            }

            // Uri.TryCreate will treat this as valid
            if (toTest.Equals("about:blank"))
            {
                return TestResult.DoNothing;
            }

            Uri url;
            if (Uri.TryCreate(toTest, UriKind.Absolute, out url))
            {
                return TestResult.TryCreatePass;
            }
            else
            {
                return TryParse(toTest);
            }
        }

        private static TestResult TryParse(string toTest)
        {
            if (!toTest.Contains("."))
            {
                return TestResult.Search;
            }

            if (!toTest.StartsWith("http://") ||
                !toTest.StartsWith("https://"))
            {
                return TestResult.ValidWithPrefix;
            }

            return TestResult.Unknown;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir, please explain me this thing. if (!toTest.Contains("."))---> In this if statement, what is the meaning of **"."**?

Comment: @RaghavMac it means "if the string doesn't contain a dot/decimal/period"

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, Matt Lacey. Please check this edited post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741439/how-to-put-an-image-on-web-browser-control)