# Full screen web browser control for wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In my web browser app for windows phone 7, i wrote a code to hide textbox and application bar. After hiding these things, i need the web browser control to stretch and make it as a full screen web browser. There is some weird things happened. If i didn't type any into the UrlTextBox and if i touched the web browser control(currently it's blank), the web browser control stretches to full screen(see image 1) but if i typed some URL into the UrlTextBox(i.e, navigated to that URL) and if i touched the web browser control(see image 2), it doesn't getting expanded. The following images can give you some idea.

Image 1-

[image]

Image 2-

[image]

The following code is used to hide the above things-

```
  private void browsers_Focus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
  { 
  UrlTextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; 
  Back.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; 
  Forward.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; 
  }
```

My .xaml Page-

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"> 
<Grid.RowDefinitions> 
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" /> 
    <RowDefinition Height="*" /> 
</Grid.RowDefinitions> 
<TextBox x:Name="UrlTextBox" Background="White" InputScope="URL" 
     KeyDown="UrlTextBox_KeyDown" Margin="0,0,98,0" GotFocus="UrlTextBox_GotFocus" LostFocus="UrlTextBox_LostFocus" KeyUp="UrlTextBox_KeyUp"/> 
<Grid x:Name="BrowserHost"  
  Grid.Row="1" GotFocus="BrowserHost_GotFocus"> 
</Grid>
```

What i need is **"If the user touches the browser control, then the browser control should stretch to full screen"**.
Can anybody help me with this? Thanks in advance for your hard word!

Comment: Looks like the browser's content is getting input focus, not the browser.  Looks like you are going to have issues trying to perform UI tasks based on the focus of that control.

Comment: Do, do you have idea about this. If the user touches the browser control, then the browser control should stretch to full screen. Can you help me this.

Comment: No, I can't.  All I can tell you is that the *content* within the control is taking focus away from the control itself.  You need to accomplish your goals a different way.  Don't know offhand which way.

Comment: Please show what you've tried. Please also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask, 
http://tinyurl.com/so-hints & 
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html Also, adding comments to old questions asking the people who answered them to look at your question isn't the way we do things round here. We're perfectly capable of finding the new, unanswered questions and will help people who are tyring to help themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the GestureListener that is part of Silverlight Toolkit ?